# Store a integer from two @IBAction func into NSUserDefaults Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm Fairly new at Swift and have been stuck on this for a while. I think it comes from not having a comprehensive understanding of the language but any help would be much appreciated.

I'm creating a basic Door Counter (for counting people arriving to an event)

```
var counterNumber = 0


@IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!
```

One button to count up

```
@IBAction func countUp(sender: UIButton) {
    counterNumber += 1
    counterLabel.text = "\(counterNumber)"
    var counterNumberAdd = counterLabel.text
    func saveCounterNumber(number:NSNumber){
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(counterNumberAdd, forKey: "addcounterNumber")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }}
```

and one to count down

```
@IBAction func countDown(sender: UIButton) {
    let countersub: () = counterNumber -= 1
    counterLabel.text = "\(counterNumber)"
    var counterNumberSub = counterLabel.text
    func saveCounterNumber(number:NSNumber){
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(counterNumberSub, forKey: "subcounterNumber")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

}
```

I was trying to store the count in the func above but am having a hard time recalling the data and creating a function that resolves the two variables and stores it in the app's NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're using NSUserDefaults, not Core Data.
2. You're saving the label's text value when you should saving counterNumber
3. You have a function within your IBAction which is frivolous and not even being called.
4. If you're trying to do a 1 up 1 down counter, you shouldn't be saving these as two different NSUserdefaults values
5. There is no need to synchronize NSUserDefaults every time
6. If you want to update your label every time the number updates, use the `didSet` observer.
7. If you're dealing with a specific type (ie. Int), you can use NSUserDefault's `integerForKey` and `setIntegerForKey`

When you put all of this together it simplifies down to:

```
@IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!

var counterNumber: Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("counterNumber") {
    didSet {
        numberLabel.text = "\(self.counterNumber)"
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    numberLabel.text = "\(self.counterNumber)"
}

@IBAction func downButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(--counterNumber, forKey: "counterNumber")
}

@IBAction func upButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(++counterNumber, forKey: "counterNumber")
}
```